# Wordpress widget page content

Tags: wordpress, widget

I have a page that is a list of entries (a link and some text).
I want to have a widget on another page that shows the first entry of this list - how do I do this?

Comment: How is this list generated and what is it made of? Posts? Custom post types?

Comment: The list is just of the form: <ul> <li> image, link, text </li> <li> image, link, text </li> </ul>

Comment: So are you typing this information in manually or is it being printed to the page with a wordpress loop?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure, I think it's a loop.

Answer (score 0):

For the recent updates you have to use plugin or posts and than display these posts on that specific page.when you create new post it will automatically will be displayed on that page.